# react router 6.4.3 typescript - useLocation any type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router-dom

[image]

How am i to fix the this any type error?

I tried passing custom type but that didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can import Location from history. So update would be like this

```
import { Location } from "history";
const location = useLocation<Location>();
```

or alternatively you can create types

```
type LocationTypes = {
  pathname: string;
  state: any; //Here you can put your data type instead of any
  search: string;
  hash: string;
  key: string;
}

const location = useLocation<LocationTypes>();
```

Comment: can't pass custom type as I'm getting "Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1."

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to resolved it, I checked the node_module for the type and I saw it there. It is the same as the `type LocationTypes` [@Evren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13544849/evren) suggested so I restarted my system and it works fine now, didn't know why it wasn't detected without having to restart my system